# Nested statements Python coding

Tags: python, nested-loops

i need help, theres something wrong in my coding and cannot seem to figure out what..im sure its a simple error its just i cant seem to find it at the moment

```
    string = raw_input("Enter String->")
    length = len(string)
    index = 0
    while index < length:
       if string(index) == 'a':
            print "Character found is a"
       index = length
       elif string(index) != 'a':
            print "Character", index"is not an a, sorry"
```

The error of course is "invalid syntax"

This is the new code so far

```
   string = raw_input("Enter String->")
   length = len(string)
   index = 0
   while index < length:
       if string[index] == 'a':
           print "Character found is a"
           index = length
       elif string[index] != 'a':
           print "Character", index,"is not an a, sorry"
```

from here when i run the code, it runs infinitely saying "character 0 is not a"

3rd Edit

```
    string = raw_input("Enter String->")
    length = len(string)
    index = 0
    while index < length:
        if string[index] == 'a':
            index += 1
            print "Character found is a"
            break
        elif string[index] != 'a':
            print "Character", index, "is not an a, sorry"
```

Comment: In your 3rd edit, you are only moving the index if the character is 'a'. As soon as you hit a character that isn't 'a', you will loop forever

Answer (score 2):

`index = length` is going to jump straight to the end of the string. You'd need to use `index += 1` instead if you want to check each character

Normally you would write the loops like this

```
string = raw_input("Enter String->")
for idx, c in enumerate(string):
   if c == 'a':
        print "Character found is a"
   else:
        print "Character", idx, "is not an a, sorry"
```

Which is easier to read and makes it much harder to make such errors

Comment: @user1695993, that's because you have ended the `if` statement when you dedented the line `index = length`

Answer (score 1):

Index access is accomplished with `[i]`, not with `(i)`, which denotes a function call.

So you should do:

```
if string[index] == 'a':
```

Also take a note of the rest of the answers about other problems with your code.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few problems:

- Use square brackets to access elements in an iterable: `a[1]`,
- Move `index = length` up one level. It is breaking your loop by being between an `if` and an `elif`.
- `print` is missing one comma.

A better way to do it would be like this:

```
string = raw_input("Enter String->")

for index, character in enumerate(string):
   if character == 'a':
        print "Character found is a"
        break
   else:
        print "Character", index, "is not an a, sorry"
```

Comment: how would i be able to do this using the same syntax above, if and elif statements also without the break, thanks.

Comment: I've outlined the problems with your code in the bullet points of my answer. Since you're learning Python, I don't want to code it for you, so try fixing it yourself and post what you did.

Comment: In your code, you never change `index`. After your `if` block, add in `index += 1` so that `index` increments every loop.

Comment: Also, `index = length` is equivalent to `break`.

Comment: i still get the same output :(

Comment: Edit your question once more with the changes that you made. You probably indented `index += 1` too much.

Comment: `index += 1` is in the wrong spot. Put it *all* the way after the entire `if` and `elif` block. It needs to happen every single time the loop loops.

Comment: in the output though it stops when it finds an a, that might've been what he wanted, either way thank you for everything, thanks everyone for all the awesome help

Answer (score 0):

```
print "Character", index"is not an a, sorry"
```

Should read

```
print "Character " + str(index) + " is not an a, sorry"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment `index` at after each loop, otherwise the while loop will run forever on the same index:

```
string = raw_input("Enter String->")
length = len(string)
index = 0
while index < length:
    if string[index] == 'a':
       print "Character found is a"
       break
    else:
       print "Character" + str(index) + " is not an a, sorry"
       index += 1
```

Though, you should study @gnibbler's suggestion and use it instead of `while` loop for this specific purpose.

Answer (score 0):

First, really quick word of advice -- using variables with names like 'string' will lead to headaches.

So, the code you've written tells me you need to see that each character *position* prior to the first 'a' but not its actual *value*, that you need to know whether 'a' is in the string, and that you do not care about any character at all after the first 'a'. These goals seem a little unlikely to me, so I suspect your real question is slightly different than what you've asked how to do.

I really see two root questions here:

**1. How do I find the index of the first 'a' in a given string?** If this is your main concern, all you need to do is

```
response = raw_input('Prompt: ')
index_a = response.find('a')
```

`foo.find(bar)` will give you the index of bar, or `-1` if it's not in foo at all. But if you don't even care where bar is, and just need to verify that it's there, use `bar in foo` instead.

**2. How do I examine each character in a string?** Python doesn't make you build your iteration in many cases -- it gives you the `for` structure, which does the gruntwork for you. This example will let you keep track of the pre-matched character positions, if you really need that, but note that `counter` has nothing at all to do with the flow control:

```
response = raw_input('Prompt: ')
counter = 0
for r in response:
    if r is 'a':
        print('We found it.')
        break
    else:
        print('Not ' + str(counter))
        counter += 1
```